# ls -a not showing folder "system", but echo * shows it

Tags: linux, centos, ls

When I create a folder named system in my home folder, or in /tmp (can't try other locations as I am not root, but owner confirmed same problem even on root), ls -a will not show it. Also tried /bin/ls -a, same deal. Otherwise the folder "works" fine, I can cd into it, pwd shows the right location and everything. I can even rename it to something else and ls will show it then. But if I rename it back to system, ls will not show it anymore. Please note even if I remove the folder completely, or create it in a location where it previously didn't exist, with "mkdir system", it will not be shown by ls unless I rename it to something else.
"echo *" shows the system folder. dir behaves same as ls (doesn't show the folder). Other folders with different names work fine and show up.

Distro is CentOS 5.6. I have another box with CentOS 5.5 and I DO NOT have this issue there. I don't think it's distro-related. I do not have root access but owner confirmed the problem on root as well.

Info about mount point from /etc/mtab:
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 / ext3 rw 0 0

Comment: How very bizarre. I'm extremely curious as to what's going on here. It sounds like something in the ls tool itself since `echo *` works.

Comment: Sounds like a compromised box.

Comment: anybody know if this is a symptom of a rootkit?

Comment: @ysth I don't think it's a rootkit (bash globs it fine).

Comment: You should `md5sum /bin/ls` and check it against another CentOS 5.6.

Comment: @Heandel: Or run a binary named something other than `md5sum` off of a USB stick, just in case `md5sum` has been fiddled too.

Comment: I encountered a rootkit (tragedy/dor) on a Solaris box 10 years ago.  It did a similar thing with any file name ending in '0'. ls failed to show the file or directory, but shell globbing and open(2) or fopen(3) worked find.

Comment: What is about a file "touch system; ls system" you get some output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `alias ls="ls | grep -v system"` would do it. Sounds like a prank or a rootkit. Were there any files within the directory?

Comment: An alias would not stop `/bin/ls` working, with the OP tried.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was a rootkit (probably BeastKit).